# How do I mark a document as final in word for mac 2011

Tags: macos, ms-office

I have searched quite a few websites and all of them tell to go into "Info" menu and under the "Permissions" group you select the document to be marked as final. The menu is available in Windows but this is not the case with Mac, I cannot find this menu. Can anyone tell how can I mark the document as final in Word 2011 for Mac?

Edit:

After marking it as final I should be able to see the following when I open the document:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Word 2011 for Mac, marking as Final is found in the **Review** ribbon.  From here you can turn on/off **Track Changes**, accept or reject changes etc.

I hope this is useful.

[image: Word 2011 Mac Review Ribbon]

Comment: I updated the question to reflect what I need more clearly. When I mark the document as final on windows I am able to see the ribbon which I added in the question. That doesn't show up when I follow the steps you mention.